# Logo in middle of nav bar without bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have a header that I would like to put a logo in the middle of. I don't want to use bootstrap unless there is no other choice. The logo appears to show in the centre of the navigation bar as I would like, however, the links do not go around it properly. Here is an example of what I want the navbar to look like in terms of positioning: [ibb.co/zsGG9FY](http://ibb.co/zsGG9FY)

```css
#firstpage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#firstpage ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#firstpage li {
  float: left;
}

#firstpage li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 33px 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#firstpage li a:hover {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .active {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .midlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#firstpage .midlogo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
```

```html
<section id="firstpage">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#firstpage">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#how-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#why-us">WHY CHOOSE US</a></li>
    <li class="midlogo">
      <a href="#firstpage"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Describe what you want us to do. The links are "going around it" just fine. To make matters worse, we also can't see that image.

Comment: You dont need to see the image. Simply, I want the header links to be central and the logo in the middle. The first three links should be to the left of the logo and the last three links should be to the right. The logo acts as the centre point. Here is an example image. https://ibb.co/zsGG9FY @Spectric

Comment: Did I provide enough information? @Spectric

Comment: I am personally seeing "the logo in the middle", and the first three/last three logos appropriately on the left/right. I'm not sure what you mean by "the header links to be central" - isn't the logo "central"? How can both be central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `float: left` on `<li>` tag so it keeps on left position. This should be removed.

And using `display: flex` layout on `ul` tag, you can align all items on center.

Attached snippet shows what you need.

```css
#firstpage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#firstpage ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#firstpage li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 33px 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#firstpage li a:hover {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .active {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .midlogo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="firstpage">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#firstpage">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#how-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#why-us">WHY CHOOSE US</a></li>
    <li class="midlogo">
      <a href="#firstpage"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked! However, the links are now split into different lines... How do I fix this? https://ibb.co/GdnkwDs @Derek.W

Comment: This is because of the screen size. On wide screen, it won't show like that. All links are on one line. It will be good to adjust the margin and padding values of `link` to avoid that problem. @slkdanfalvsd

Comment: Which margin and padding? I tried a few things and none of them did work. Which part of the code should I change? @Derek.W

Comment: `#firstpage li a`, you have set `padding: 33px 19px`, pls adjust that.

Comment: I have tried adjusting it to `padding: 33px 40px;` and it did not fix the issue. It simply moves the text over and makes the image smaller. @Derek.W

Comment: You have to reduce the padding size, not increasing the padding size.

Comment: This is due to `#firstpage .midlogo img { width: 100%; height: 100%;`. If I set it to a fixed width and height (for eg, 50px and 50px), the text goes back to normal. But, the logo is not entered. @Derek.W

Comment: Then add `white-space: nowrap` on `#firstpage li a` class.

Comment: The logo is still not in the centre @Derek.W

Comment: However, the text is fixed.

Comment: It is hard to avoid the `line-wrap` on small screen sizes. The only way is to adjust the spaces well to fit that. It seems the screen width is smaller than the `min-width` the ul needs.

Comment: If it helps, I am on a MacBook 13" screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222877/discussion-between-derek-w-and-slkdanfalvsd).

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the classes containing `float: left` for `li` items and `position: absolute` for `.midlogo` item respectively.

All you need is `flex` property inside `ul` item to adjust its **1 dimensional** layout.

```css
#firstpage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#firstpage ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

  /************ ADD FLEX DISPLAY ************/
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


#firstpage li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 33px 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#firstpage li a:hover {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .active {
  color: #00CFFF;
}


#firstpage .midlogo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="firstpage">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#firstpage">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#how-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#why-us">WHY CHOOSE US</a></li>
    <li class="midlogo">
      <a href="#firstpage"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

You should read about the `flex` property- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: For some reason, this is the output. Im not sure why this is happening. I believe it has something to do with the logo image. https://ibb.co/2yGv7f1 @Sapinder

Comment: try to remove `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` from `img`, and add ***fixed*** dimensions to it

Comment: The issue is, I want the logo to be in the centre of the nav bar, and the links to the left and right of the logo but centred so it doesn't look disproportionate. @Sapinder

Comment: There is a picture of the output @Sapinder

Comment: The issue you showed in the 1st comment to my answer clearly shows that the other `li` items are separated because of `img` taking up a whole row. Defining fixed dimensions of `img` should fix the issue. If not, try to add `flex-grow: 0` to `li.midlogo` class

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses Flexbox. I've replaced the image with an element with a dashed border so that it's obvious where it is. I've also but a pink background behind each link to show that they are indeed all the same width.

Each normal link has a width of 100% to force them to take up all available space. The logo has `flex-shrink:0` so that it retains it's given size.

```css
#firstpage ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#firstpage li {
  width: 100%;
}
#firstpage li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: pink;
}

#firstpage li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 33px 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#firstpage li a:hover {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .active {
  color: #00CFFF;
}

#firstpage .midlogo {
  border: white dashed 3px;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="firstpage">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#firstpage">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#how-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#why-us">WHY CHOOSE US</a></li>
    <li class="midlogo">
      <a href="#firstpage"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```